# SDN6 - Projection interfaces with Property Mapping

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using spring data neo4j 6.1.3 and following is my use case code snippets

Domain Entity

```
    @Data
    @Node("DATspace")
    public class DatSpace {

      @Id @GeneratedValue
      private Long neoId;

      @Property("SUPtitle")
      private String title;

      private String SUPid;
    }
```

Test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.rahal.marvel")
public class ProjectionTest {

   @Autowired
   private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

   interface DATspaceProjection {
      String getTitle();
      String getSUPid();
   }

   @Test
   public void test_projection(){
      DatSpace d = neo4jTemplate.findOne("MATCH (s:DATspace {SUPid: $id}) RETURN s", Collections.singletonMap("id", "SPC_ML7"), DatSpace.class).get();

      d.setTitle("title modified");
      d.setSUPid("SUPid modified");

      DATspaceProjection   p = neo4jTemplate.saveAs(d, DATspaceProjection.class);
   }
}
```

Ideally above saveAs function should modify both DATspace.SUPtitle and DATspace.SUPid. However it only modify SUPid but not SUPtitle. I presume it is due to property mapping (@Property) . Is this a bug or are there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided `@Property` annotation does only have an impact on the annotated property (`title`) itself.
There is no knowledge right now that goes from the `getTitle()` method in the projection to the annotated `title` field in the domain class.

To be safe when modifying this use the explicit property name:

```
interface DATspaceProjection {
    String getSUPtitle();
    String getSUPid();
}
```

I created an issue for improvement https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2371

Comment: Using  explicit property name did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: however you will not be able to read this property back this way at the moment. SDN 6.3 will most likely support this in the future, but also fix the underlying issue.